# Jquery focus out after pressing enter key

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

My code is below:

```
$('.summaryT').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){
        callajax();
        $(this).focusout();

    }
});
```

As you can see on the code above, When a user presses the enter key first `callajax()` is run(working fine). After that I want to focus out from the `.summaryT` input box, How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.summaryT').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){
        callajax();
        $(this).blur();    
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since AJAX stands for asynchronous, you may want to call `focusout()` after the call successfully finished.

Answer (score 1):

use the jquery [blur()](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event

```
$('.summaryT').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){
        callajax();
        $(this).blur();

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## Here is the solution even if Mousetrap is activated

```
    $('.selectorClass').keypress(function(e)
    {
        if(e.which == 13)
        {
            // 13 is a code to hit keyboard enter button
            alert('Enter is pressed');
        }
    });

    $('#selectorID').keypress(function(e)
    {
        if(e.which == 13)
        {
            // 13 is a code to hit keyboard enter button
            alert('Enter is pressed');
        }
    });
```